# Spring 3 JavaConfig - Problems Injecting DataSource

Tags: java, spring, datasource, code-injection

I'm new to Spring and I'm trying to my DataSource injection to work. I'm getting a "Property 'dataSource' is required" error. Been stumped on this for a while. Thanks in advance for your help!

**WebConfig.java**

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
DataSource Source;

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    System.out.println("addResourceHandlers :: init");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(
            "/resources/");
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    System.out.println("viewResolver :: init");
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}

}
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test" })
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    System.out.println("userDBDatasource :: init");
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
    dataSource.setUsername("foo");
    dataSource.setPassword("foo");
    return dataSource;
}

}
```

**JDBCUserDaoImpl.java**

```
package com.test.foo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class JDBCUserDAOImpl implements JDBCUserDAO {

private Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    logger.debug("setDataSource :: called");
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

public List<UserBean> getUsers() {
    logger.info("Getting List of Users!");
    List<UserBean> userBeans = new ArrayList<UserBean>();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    userBeans = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new UserBeanRowMapper());
    return userBeans;
}
}
```

**Error**

```
Dec 07, 2013 10:46:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [main] in context with path [/springmvc] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.afterPropertiesSet(JdbcAccessor.java:134)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.<init>(JdbcTemplate.java:165)
    at com.tajima.models.JDBCUserDAOImpl.getUsers(JDBCUserDAOImpl.java:42)
    at com.tajima.controllers.HomeController.loadUserList(HomeController.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: And how you are loading these configuration files. A performance tip on your DAAO, you shouldn't be creating a `JdbcTemplate` each time you need one, construct it once then reuse.

Comment: Show us how you get an instance of the DAO in your controller. My guess is that you're using `new JDBCUserDAOImpl()` to get one, instead of using dependency injection.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I haven't understood this quite well. I thought using the autowired annotation on my setDataSource method would make Spring inject my DataSource bean.

Comment: Update - realized I wasnt injecting the JDBCTemplate containing the datasource into my controller! Doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @Import annotation provides just this kind of support, and it is the direct equivalent of the  element found in Spring beans XML files.

You have missed to import AppConfig class to the WebMvcConfig class file. So, spring unable to create the bean with the name 'dataSource'.

In your WebMvcConfig class you need to import the DataSource configuration class with @Import annotation. This will helps to create dataSource bean by the spring Container.

```
 ex:@Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @Import({AppConfig.class})
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test")
    public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
```

I hope have correctly specified webConfig class as contextConfigLocation param to the Dispatcher servlet. if it is not there specify as specified below

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
  <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>yourpackage.config.WebMvcConfig</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

or you can specify this context class and contextConfiglocation to the ContextLoaderLister as a context param as specified below

```
   <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
 <context-param>
<param-name>contextClass</param-name>
<param- value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationC     ontext</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>yourpackage.WebMvcConfig</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the DataSource injection from WebConfig.java